# How to make a shadow catcher be able to see things behind it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using blender 2.83. I am trying to make a shadow catcher. But it needs to be able to see an Image behind it when I render it. Here is an image:

[image: I need to yellow part to be able to see the image behind it. But It still be a shadow catcher]

I need to yellow part to be able to see the image behind it. But It still be a shadow catcher.

If someone could tell me how to do this. That would be great!

**Here is the link to the .Blend file:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lxsJGJdQFgZ1aWXAy_etywFz-zV8I5s2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you using an image as it's own textured object behind your shadow catcher?

Comment: I used the images as planes addon to import the image